# Шрифты. Поддержка немецкого языка

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Как проверить, поддерживает ли шрифт немецкий язык?
Допустим в google fonts, нужно ли как-то дополнительно настраивать, чтобы шрифт поддерживал немецкий язык?

Comment: В google fonts нужно, что бы шрифт умел Latin Extended. В немецком всего 4 лишних буквы

Comment: Откройте любой сайт de, хотя бы spiegel.de или любой который знаете. При использовании utf-8 ни разу не видел проблемы с немецким. Только на соовсем старых страницах в соовсем старых браузерах встречались глюки лет... более 10 назад.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, подскажите, хотелось-бы понять, на сайте используется тема, в этой теме установлены несколько шрифтов. Допустим у шрифта open-sans  есть ещё выпадающий список с возможными вариантами: `Latin, Latin extended, Greek, Greek extended, vietnamese`. Допустим в чём разница `Greek и Greek extended`?

Comment: Open Sans подходит практически ко всем западным языкам. В Greek extended есть символы греческого политонического. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA "До 1982 года на письме использовалась богатая политоническая система диакритики"